# sql query check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select *
from ServerActivity 
inner join ServerBackup on ServerActivity.fid=ServerBackup.id 
where ServerBackup.servertype=:ServerBackup.servertype 
and ServerActivity.BK_date between ServerActivity.BK_Date=:ServerActivity.BK_Date 
and erverActivity.BK_Date=:ServerActivity.BK_Date
```

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '='2020-01-31' and
>   erverActivity.BK_Date='2020-01-31'' at line 1

Comment: Please replace your query with placeholders and show the query text with the parameters values inserted into.

Answer (score 0):

1. A space after '*' is needed.
2. The 'erverActivity' needs an 'S'.
3. The comparison dates appear the same? i.e. between
   ServerActivity.BK_Date and ServerActivity.BK_Date ?
4. MySQL has no '=:' operator.
5. The date comparison types may not match, try cast the strings to dates prior to comparing via
   [Str_To_Date](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/)

Answer (score 0):

If `:ServerBackup.servertype` and `:ServerActivity.BK_Date` are placeholders for parameters transferred into the query then test:

```
Select *
from ServerActivity 
inner join ServerBackup on ServerActivity.fid = ServerBackup.id 
where ServerBackup.servertype = :ServerBackup.servertype 
  and ServerActivity.BK_date between :ServerActivity.BK_Date and :ServerActivity.BK_Date
```

PS. Don't save bytes, add spaces where they make sense. There are places where spaces  are required...

PPS. `and ServerActivity.BK_date between :ServerActivity.BK_Date and :ServerActivity.BK_Date` is `and ServerActivity.BK_date = :ServerActivity.BK_Date`...